# No puedo mostrar ítem seleccionado de dropdownlist

Tags: c#

Me encuentro realizando un proyecto y necesito guardar en una variable el valor seleccionado de un dropdownlist que es llenado con un List. He intentado de muchas formas y siempre me saca el primer valor del list.

Esta es la lista con la que se llena el dropdownlist:

```
Lista<String> lista = new Lista<String>();
```

Así lleno el dropdownlist:

```
this.dropdownlist.DataSource = lista;
this.dropdownlist.DataBind();
```

Así es como saco el valor seleccionado:

```
string recuperado;
recuperado = dropdownlist.SelectedItem.Value;
```

Siempre me saca el primer valor de la lista.
Espero y me puedan asesorar.

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: hagas lo que hagas recuperado siempre tiene le mismo valor? y si no seleccionas nada? donde estas verificando el valor del dropdown?

Comment: tu dropdownlist tiene habilitada la propiedad autoPosBack en "true"?

Comment: Siempre y cuando estemos hablando de web.. que no lo aclara @OmarViñas, pero es una buena pregunta. Es web?

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que cuando asignas los datos del dropdownlist en el `Page_Load` debes ponerlo dentro del `IsPostBack`

```
public void Page_Load(...){

    if(!IsPostBack){
        this.dropdownlist.DataSource = lista;
        this.dropdownlist.DataBind();
    }

}
```

Cuando se produce el request de un evento al servidor pasa siempre por el Load, sino validas que no sea parte de postback se recargara los items del combo y perderas la seleccion

Si lo haces de esta forma el [SelectedValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) tendra el valor selecionado por el usuario

Comment: Cierto, todo se soluciono con el postback.